# Library/Framework for Parsing Output from Commandline (C#)?

Tags: c#, parsing, command-line

My application needs to:

1. Run an external command-line application
2. Capture the standard output/error during execution
3. Parse the data from the output/error and use it for status display in the main app

While it's not hard to do it, it seems to me it's a very common task, and I was wondering if there's a library or framework simplifying this task in C#.

Edit: Here's a "Mono.Options inspired" example of the kind of thing I'm looking for:

```
ProcessWithParser proc= new ProcessWithParser(filename, arguments);
proc.AddWatch("percent=??", v => this.percent = Convert.ToInt32(v));
proc.Start();
```

In the "concept" above, it would locate "percent=" in the output, read the next two characters as a string, and call the delegate using this string as a parameter.

Comment: I can't see how there'd be commonality, as the format will entirely depend on the command-line application.

Comment: Regex should make it a breeze.

Comment: a breeze or a gale? maybe a hurricane?

Comment: I added a "concept" of what I was thinking of implementing if I don't find anything for the task. Should give you a better idea of what I'm talking about.

Comment: I should hope this is much less of a common task than it used to be, especially considering PowerShell. We can do much better than returning text that has to be parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base class library provides the tools for this already - there isn't much a framework would really need to add to it.

Redirection of the process [standard input and output streams is trivial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ProcessStartDemo.aspx).  RegEx and using streams makes parsing this fairly easy, as well.

The framework pretty much does what any (flexible) custom library would normally do in other languages.

Comment: Ended up writing my own code to suit my needs, but since I can't release it on the web I'm accepting this answer as the "best option available for the general public".